# convert string into class name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a variable `handler` whose value can be `flight_gds, flight_commission etc.`

There are `classes` in my application which has names like `FlightGds, FlightCommission` etc. under `module FlightManager`.

I want to execute the function of class based on the value of the handler.
 
The **function name is same** in all classes, only **the class name is different** which is dependent on
the handler.

**For example:** 
If handler name is '`flight_gds`', then the function is `FlightManager::FlightGds.calculate()`

I am trying something like this:

```
FlightManager::handler.camelize.calculate()
```

But I am getting `undefined method handler` error.

Is there any way to do this or I should go with `if/else` loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [`constantize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) to get a class based on it's name in string:

```
"FlightManager::#{handler.camelize}".constantize.calculate())
```